# Replace Sqlite file on iOS - Core data error 14

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nspersistentstore

I have a Sqlite file with preloaded data. I am using Core Data to read and display data from the Sqlite file.

Here is how I am reading the data:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL;


        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myAppname" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];



    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    // This dictionary automatically updates and migrates the store if it changes
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO], NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption,
                             nil];

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
         @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        if (error) {
            [myErrorAlert showError:error];
        }

        CLS_LOG(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

However I need to update the Sqlite file with new data which I did outside the app with sqlite data editor.

Now when I copy-paste and override "myAppname.sqlite" file, I get the following error:

```
CoreData: error: (14) I/O error for database at /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/45C373D7-8A54-48EF-BA3C-2E2C6AB7467F/myAppname.app/myAppname.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'
```

I did try to add `NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"}` but still the same error exists.

Also some answers suggested to remove reference to file and create a new one, but I have no idea how to do it.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I have manage to get it working.

Open original app on iOS 6 simulator.

Repalce Sqlite file with new file and run App only iOS 6 simulator than run on iOS7 simulator. NO issue.

However still would like to know other comments.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @GrantIsom Sorry for delay in reply. I did manage to do it. Please change my edited Question.

Comment: Have you tried on a real device? I ended up having to convert the type to NSBinaryType to get it to work.

Comment: @GrantIsom It did work on devices too, however I can not answer with full confidant as it was few months back.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, where you just moving it within the same app, or to a watch app or extension?